# Divergence between two PDFs - Upper bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, divergence-operator

> Consider the following conditional probability density function:
>   $$\mathbb{P}_{X_1,\ldots,X_n|Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n},Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n|y_0,\ldots,y_{n},q)=\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda e^{-\lambda (x_i-r_i)}$$
>   where $r_i=\max{\{0,\sum_{j=1}^{i}{y_j}}-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}{x_j}-q\}$, and
>   $$\mathbb{P'}_{X_1,\ldots,X_n|Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n},Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n|y_0,\ldots,y_{n},q)=\prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda/\alpha_i) e^{-\lambda (x_i/\alpha_i-r'_i)}$$
>   where $r'_i=\max{\{0,\sum_{j=1}^{i}{y_j}}-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}{x_j/\alpha_j}-q\}$.
>   Find a (preferably or relatively) tight upperbound for
>   $$\mathcal{D}_{KL}(\mathbb{P' ||P})$$where $\mathcal{D}_{KL}(\cdot)$ is the Kullback_Liebler divergene.

**My Solution:**
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}_{KL}(\mathbb{P' ||P}) &= \int \mathbb{P'} \log{\frac{\mathbb{P'}}{\mathbb{P}}}dx_1 \ldots dx_n\\
&= \int \mathbb{P'}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(-\log{(\alpha_i)}-\lambda (x_i/\alpha_i-r'_i)+\lambda (x_i-r_i)\right)dx_1 \ldots dx_n\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\alpha_i)+\int \mathbb{P'}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left({\left({\mathbb{{-\lambda (x_i/\alpha_i-r'_i)}}+{\lambda (x_i-r_i)}}\right)}\right)dx_1 \ldots dx_n\\
\end{align}

Because of the $r_i$s, I have difficulty in calculating this, any idea how to do this?